# Scala/Java/Linux: is it possible to monitor a system process passively?

Tags: java, linux, scala, process, centos

Let's say I have to build a Scala application that will alert me if one of specified system processes stops running.

Is there a passive way to accomplish this as opposed to running an endless loop every few seconds of something like `"pidof process_name" !` (executes shell command in scala)?

If Scala/Java is not capable of this, is there something I could have in the middle that would make this work? My `JNI` and `C` skills are rusty at best, but I would give it a shot if that really is the only way.

The operating system in question is Centos 6.4

**UPDATE:** I've found something called "upstart" which apparently is used by quite a few linux distros now (including Centos 6.4) to manage processes. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909798/how-to-know-if-a-process-had-been-started-but-crashed-in-linux) it may be capable of what I need, although not a lot of information is given.

Comment: If you know the PID of the process, you can set up a directory watcher on  `/proc` and react if said PID disappears by reacting to the appropriate event. Requires JDK 7.

Comment: @fge Yes, I'm aware of WatchService and although this approach could work, it's tricky, because some services run on multiple PIDs - simple example would be nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Couple standard options:

1. You can schedule this script to run via crontab every 5 mins for example like this:

   ```
   */5 * * * * /install_dir/app_monitor.sh
   ```

   The script itself `app_monitor.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Application name
   appName="jar"

   # find all app instances
   procCount=$(ps -ef | grep "$appName" | egrep -v grep | wc -l)
   if [ "$procCount" -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "No applications running."
     mutt -e 'my_hdr From:admin@dreamapp.com' -s "Your app just died yo, time: $(date)." your@email.com -c yourhome@email.com < "More useful info or log file here"
     # or use sendmail, or any other notification option
     exit 1
   else
     echo "Something is running."
   fi
   ```

   This finds an app by name, or regex - adjust accordingly.
2. Another option would be to use [fcntl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) file locking which is what Java standard [library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) uses on Linux. You lock the pid file and keep it locked while application is running. A lock can be checked from any program whether its C, Java or shell script (lsof). If process dies a lock will be released by OS so you always know whether the process is dead or alive. If that process is a C program that forks off child processes then those will not inherit the lock by default.

   I once done that implementation on Linux for apps that worked together and it was implemented in Python, Perl, Java, C, and shell scripts. It was used to avoid startup of multiple instances of the same app and for monitoring.
3. Use readymade tools like nagios: http://www.nagios.com/solutions/linux-process-monitoring/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper script that starts your process and then simply waits for its termination. You should be able to write the wrapper script in Bash or Scala (or other shell). After termination the wrapper can register the event with your Scala monitoring application.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I don't think it's the right approach for me. I'd like to leave the processes as they are.

Comment: As far as I know the only wait to accomplish passive monitoring (not polling) is with some sort of event generation. A wrapper startup script seems like the easiest. The only other options I can think of are fairly complex. It will be interesting to see what solutions you get. Cheers!